# How install python-devel without package management?

Tags: python

When I install some python-packages, system always report “fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory”. Therefore, I must install python-dev on my linux machine. However I don't have root privilege and can't use yum or pip from network because it's company's develop machine. I try to download Python-dev source code from

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/Sources/Vanilla%20Sources/_Deprecated/python-dev/.

But I don't know how to install it. What should I do? Thx!

Comment: Is talking to your admin team to get it installed possible? If it's a development machine, this request is quite reasonable...

Comment: Python is now hosted on github https://github.com/python/cpython Follow the instruction in the README.rst to build it